# Are you an English student or teacher? Do you want some free food?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If so, I would love to talk to you about the Stack Exchange Ambassadors program. Our goal is to get students and teachers involved in promoting Stack Exchange EL&U. Basically, Stack Exchange wants to sponsor study breaks, research meetings, or social events for academic groups by providing free food and Stack Exchange gear. We're looking for people in the English community who want to organize these events and represent Stack Exchange to their classmates/students.

If you are interested, please respond to this post or email academics@stackexchange.com.

Note: this is also happening on

- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/introducing-linguistics-se-university-ambassadors-program-calling-students-and)
- [Theoretical Comp Sci](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/se-theoretical-cs-pizza-ambassador-program-sponsored-discussion-groups)
- [Statistics](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/948/introducing-crossvalidated-se-pizza-ambassadors-program-calling-students-and-te)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/917/introducing-physics-se-university-ambassadors-program-calling-students-and-teac)
- [Theoretical Physics](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/171/are-you-an-physics-student-or-teacher-do-you-want-some-free-food)
- [Music](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274/are-you-a-college-student-studying-music-or-a-music-teacher-and-like-free-food)

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently an American studies student and I'm always up for free food, but I'm not too keen on organizing a StackExchange themed event.

What I *would* consider doing without  much hesitation, though, is pass a leaflet around. I could also imagine the Uni staff to welcome the information, and pass some on as well.

My idea would be something that is, say, A5 big, and contains everything important about the SE model (also the CC-Wiki model and the free-ness of it all; ideally if it had to convince me, also a paragraph about how the whole thing finances itself, because there is no free lunch) and the specific site in a nutshell. It would also be cool if it had the site's design.

> Update: This has now materialized! And it looks great.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I will email you so we can discuss.

Comment: Did the leaflet ever materialize?

Comment: @Moshe yes, it did! Looks fine, too. Haven't printed it out yet though. Lauren, is it available in a public place?

Comment: Pinging @Lauren so she gets notified too. Because you can't notify two people in one comment, because that apparently would create more noise

Comment: Heh, thanks @Pekka. I'm trying to get one going for my English class's pre-final discussion group.

Comment: @Moshe you got mail

Comment: @Pekka Hrm... Not seeing anything.

Comment: @Pekka - The only email I have in my spam is from someone claiming to be Col. Gaddafi's son.

Comment: @Moshe strange! But maybe it'll arrive with a delay, I've had similar issues recently. To speed things up: http://pekkagaiser.com/stuff/english-leaflets.pdf

Comment: @Pekka - Looks awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Moshe yeah, doesn't it! It's really nice work.

Comment: @Moshe the leaflet is available [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/english-se-pamphlet-hang-up-or-hand-out-to-your-friends-and-classmates).